# Pymongo - Remove an element from array

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to remove an element from array:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56728dac7e30ad640af52a88"), "key" : "inbox", "notify" : false, "unread" : [ "5" ], "user" : "admin" }
```

I tried with this query `mgr.db.update_one({"key":"inbox","user":"admin"},{"$pull":{"unread.5":""}})` and also `mgr.db.update_one({"key":"inbox","user":"admin"},{"$pull":{"unread":{"5":""}})`, both does not remove the element from the array. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

> The [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/update/pull/#pull) operator has the form:
>
> `{ $pull: { <field1>: <value|condition>, <field2>: <value|condition>, ... } }`

Which means the correct query is:

```
mgr.db.collection.updateOne(
    { "key": "inbox", "user": "admin"},
    { "$pull": { "unread": "5" } }
)
```